# What's the best approach to create opening hours model for a store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

I would like to store an display OpeningHours for stores like this slots example:

mon = 9h00 => 12h00, 14h30 => 20H00

tue = 9H00 => 20H00

we = 14h15 => 20h00

thu = closed

I need to use it for OpeningOursSpecifications from Schema.org

Comment: Which database are you using? Postgres has very useful range types for this.

Comment: Yes I'm using postgresql but I am a beginner ;)

Answer (score 2):

Rails does not support JSONB well, and this is a perfect fit for a conventional relation.

However, ***do not*** create a table with 28 columns. If you find yourself making lists as columns, you probably have a design problem. Instead, make a table with one row for each day-of-week/open/close time.

```
create_table :store_hours do |t|
  t.references :store, null: false

  # Store the day of week using an integer and then
  # Use ActiveRecord::Enum to turn it into strings.
  t.day_of_week :integer, null: false

  # Use the Time and Interval types so you can do time math easily.
  t.open_at :time, null: false
  t.close_at :time, null: false
end

class StoreHour < ApplicationRecord do
  belongs_to :store

  enum :day_of_week, monday: 0, tuesday: 1, wednesday: 2, thursday: 3, friday: 4, saturday: 5, sunday: 6

  # Check if new hours overlap with exisiting hours.
  validates :open_at,
    scope: [:store_id, :day_of_week]
    conditions: ->(store_hour) {
      where(
        "open_at <= ? and close_at => ?",
        store_hour.close_at, store_hour.open_at
      ) 
    }
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord do
  # A store has many store hours. They will be deleted when the store is.
  # Deleting is ok here, not destroy, because there's nothing special to do
  # when the StoreHours are deleted.
  has_many :store_hours, dependent: :delete
end
```

This lets a store have as complicated an open/close time as they want.

See [Building Complex Forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) for how to write the controller and view to add, edit, and remove StoreHours.

Some comments:

- See [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for how dependent works and how to work with the associated StoreHours.
- I've added a [unique validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) to ensure a store does not have any overlapping opening/closing times. See [validates_uniqueness_of](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) and [Active Record Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).
- The day of week is stored as an integer. The class uses [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to map between integers and strings. This lets you still refer to values as `"monday"` but it is stored as a number to save space and time and to prevent typos. I've made the mapping between strings and numbers explicit in case more days need to be added (for example: weekends, holidays).
- With this model, stores must close before midnight.
- If you instead store when a store opens and how long its opened as an [interval](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#interval), stores to be open after midnight. For example, `open_at: 12pm, open_for: 13 hours` means from noon to 1am the next day. This is more complicated, but also more flexible.
- Alternatively, you can store open_at/closed_at as timestamps, but always use the same date: 2000-01-01. A store that is closed after midnight would be 2000-01-02.
- The [Postgres time type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) is mapped to a Ruby Time object, but with the date 2000-01-01.
- We use `has_many :store_hours, dependent: :delete` to ensure when a store is destroyed its StoreHours are also deleted.
- Here is [a demonstration of the time overlap validation logic](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b7d9b765b46eefc45659ff73b2d025ac).

Comment: interesting approach, but how can you do if the store have a lunch break ?

Comment: @Ben Have two StoreHours for the same store on the same day.

Comment: Yes but how do you do that, with the form ??

Comment: @Ben See [Building Complex Forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms).

Comment: The question is not how to build the form, but rather the ux approach ;)

Comment: @Ben Building Complex Forms covers the basics, and [formtastic](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic) is useful, but that should be another question.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question...

I would create models as follows:

```rb
class Store
  has_many :day_hours
end

class DayHour
  #columns day, am_open, am_closed, pm_open, pm_closed, store_id

  belongs_to :store

  enum day: Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES
end
```

I definitely would not use jsonb for the hours, why not use columns? In my experience there are always downsides to jsonb that come up later (searching records, changing values, sorting... etc)

The enum column is optional, it gives you some nice methods to use.

Answer (score 0):

For relational database use 5 columns table:

```
store_id
dayofweek    (enumerated type: 1-Sun..7-Sat)
period_begin (time type, including)
period_end   (time type, excluding)
period_type  (enumerated type: 1-opened, 2-whatever_state1, ...)
```

Treat the store as closed by default and store only records with other types (like opened).

```
1 2 9:30  12:00 1 (opened)
1 2 14:00 18:00 1 (opened)
1 3 9:00  20:00 1 (opened)
1 4 0:00  24:00 2 (whatever_state1)
1 5 0:00  24:00 3 (whatever_state2)
```

If stores and users are in different time zones you may store period_begin/end in UTC and calculate and show local time and day of a week accordingly user's timezone.

Comment: The "closed" status is redundant and invites bugs: overlapping open and closed times, missing closed times. Is it necessary?